# How to search near by place of a record having multiple places using latitude and longitude

Tags: php, mysql

For example a single record having two places like chennai and bangalore. so, this record has stored in database with 2 latitude and 2 longitude like latitude and longitude of chennai, latitude and longitude of bangalore stored in database as latitude1, latitude2 and longitude1, longitude2.
Now i want to retrieve this data if user search as bangalore or chennai within the radius of 50 km less or more distance.
Right now i am using following query for single place only.

```
SELECT *, (3959 * acos(cos(radians($Latitude)) * cos(radians(latitude)) 
          * cos(radians(longitude) - radians($Longitude)) 
          + sin(radians($Latitude)) * sin(radians(latitude )))) 
          AS distance 
    FROM MyTableName HAVING distance < $Distance ORDER BY distance
```

table structure

```
    name       |   latitude1   |    latitude2  |   longitude1   | longitude2
    -----------|---------------|---------------|----------------|--------------
   record1     |    13.0827    |   none        |  80.2707       |  none
    -----------|---------------|---------------|----------------|---------------
   record2     |   12.9716     |   13.0827     |  77.5946       |  80.2707
```

Comment: Why are you saving two locations in a single record? What's wrong with the query you're using right now?

Comment: for example one person living in bangalore and chennai alternately. so i want to show this record if search as chennai or bangalore.

Comment: right now i am having query for only one place like chennai or bangalore

Comment: What if a person lives in three places? These should be separate records joined by a foreign key.

Comment: can you give a code?

Comment: Sorry, that's now how Stack Overflow works. Search the internet for "many-to-one database relationship". Read about this idea, then try it out. If you run into any problems feel free to come back here with specific questions. (This should also simplify what you're trying to do in _this_ question: you won't have to consider multiple locations for each record.)